# Mongoose find all documents with a given ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a photo model and every photo has a vehicle associated with it:

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;
var photoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String},
    path: { type: String},
    vehicle: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Vehicle' }
  });
```

What query can I perform to return all photos that match a given vehicle `_id`?  I think the query looks the same as a normal find, but I'm not sure how to turn an `_id` into an `ObjectId.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to turn anything, your `ObjectId` itself is `_id` but in `string` format when you send it through JSON to somewhere. Try following:

```
Photo.find({vehicle: id}, function(err, result){...});
```

Above `id` is just your `vehicle`'s `ObjectId` obtained from any source e.g. User Interface